# how to exit from module in python?

Tags: python

I have several python scripts. First script is needed to store a logic of creation of the object, rest scripts import the object from the first script and work with it. My trouble is about first script: it firstly check if pickle file corresponding to object exist, and if it exists, script load object from pickle file and stop executing. So how can I stop execution of first script without terminating python iterpretator?

The first script(let name it as create_main_object.py) looks like:

```
import pickle
import os
with open('main_object', 'rb') as input1:
    main_object = pickle.load(input1)
    exit() #this currently terminate interpretator
....
###logic for creation main_object
...
with open('main_object', 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(main_object, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

The other script import main_object in the way:

```
from create_main_object import main_object
```

Comment: Put the stuff into a function, call that function in the script's body, then `return` from that function?

Comment: `exit()` is not meant to be used in actual programs, it exists for the REPL.

Comment: I have 60 lines of code for creating main object(in case there is no pickle file) and I looking for a way to not put it into big "if" or big function. I think that additional tab make my code less clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tidy up your module, and put different actions in different functions.
If you have an action that creates an object, say `main_object`, then encapsulate that logic inside a function:

```
def main_object_factory():
    with open('main_object', 'rb') as input1:
        return pickle.load(input1)
```

Then, import that specific function from your module:

```
from create_main_object import main_object_factory
```

For your information, this is called the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).